# Resumable Upload and Show Percentage of Upload using Drive API v3 on Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api, drive

I tried to find a way to do Resumable Upload and resuming it using the Drive API v3 on Python 3.5. I came across Google's Official API Guide on [Media Upload](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/media_upload) however it used the file.insert function which seems to not be available in v3.

Additionally, I also planned to upload large files so a progress bar/percentage could really help. Also, do you think I should be using Chunk Upload? Google's [official docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#resumable) seems to say there's a lost in performance.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> **the files.insert function which seems to not be available in v3.**

files.insert method was changed to [files.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create) in v3. You can check that out in the [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration).

> **I also planned to upload large files so a progress bar/percentage**

If you want to show progress bars, check out some HTML5 and JS tutorials on the web like [this one](https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-file-upload-progress-bar/). There's plenty on the web for additional samples.

> **do you think I should be using Chunk Upload?**

Resumable upload is good for big files as opposed to simple upload. So if you're working with large files, then that's the recommended way.

> [Resumable
>   upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#resumable):
>   uploadType=resumable. For reliable transfer, especially important with
>   larger files. With this method, you use a session initiating request,
>   which optionally can include metadata. This is a good strategy to use
>   for most applications, since it also works for smaller files at the
>   cost of one additional HTTP request per upload.